Understanding LWE's Correctness Proof
In this paper, on page 33, we are presented with Claim 5.2 which is supposed to show that for the selected parameters in LWE, namely:

$\alpha(n)=o(1/(\sqrt{n}\log n))$
$p\ge 2$ and $n^2<p<2n^2$  and is a prime
$m=(1+\varepsilon)(n+1)\bmod p, \varepsilon > 0$

It holds that $$\Pr_{e\sim\chi^{\star k}}\left[|e|<\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}\right] > 1-\delta(n)$$Where $\delta(n)$ is a negligible function in $n$.
I am having trouble understanding the proof, specifically why the sample taken from $\chi^{\star k}$ which is the same as $\sum_{i=1}^k{\lfloor px_i\rceil\bmod{p}}$, and the difference between it and the value $\sum_{i=1}^k{px_i}\bmod p$  is at most $k\le m<\frac{p}{32}$.
Initially I thought it might be due to the difference in magnitude (where $m=O(n\log n), p=O(n^2)$, but in that case, the $\frac{p}{32}$ could be some other constant (for example $\frac{p}{12}$).
Then I saw this paper which talks about the standard deviation.
Thinking about it more I though that it might be something along the lines of $k$ times the standard deviation, however this doesn't actually help me.
I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure this out.
Thanks.

Not marking as the answer because I am not fully sure that this is the correct answer to this question.
This is what I came up with after consulting with friends, it does check out, but might not be the right way to solve it:
Theorem: If for some $m=1.1n\log p$ and $n^2<p<2n^2$ is a prime, it holds that for any $k\in\{0,1,...,m\}$:$$\Pr_{e\sim\chi^{\star k}}\left[|e|<\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}\right] > 1-\delta(n)$$for some negligible function in $n$: $\delta(n)$.
Proof: We first want to clarify the following:$$\text{Sampling }\chi^{\star k}=\text{Sampling }\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}^{\star k}$$
The latter half is sampling the additive sum distribution of the discretization of $\Psi_{\alpha}$ for $k$. Since $\Psi_{\alpha}$ is the normal distribution (with defined variance and mean according to the overview section) in $\mathbb{T}$, it means that every value sampled from $\Psi_{\alpha}$ will be in $[0,1)$. This means that multiplying it by $p$, will yield a value that is distributed in accordance with the $\Psi_{\alpha}$ distribution but scaled by a factor of $p$.
Due to the above, we can deduce that sampling a single value from $\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}$ is identical to sampling a value from $\Psi_{\alpha}$, scaling it by $p$ and getting the whole part of it:$$x\sim\Psi_{\alpha}\rightarrow \lfloor px\rceil\sim\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}$$
Furthering this idea, we can safely say that sampling from the additive sum distribution $\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}^{\star k}$ is equal to sampling $k$ values from $\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}$, scaling each by a factor of $p$, rounding and then performing modulo $p$ on the resulting value:$$\begin{array}{c}x_1\sim\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}, x_2\sim\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha},...,x_k\sim\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}\\\\
    x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lfloor px_i\rceil\bmod{p}\\\\
    x\sim\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}^{\star k}\end{array}$$
Given normal probability distributions we know that $\Pr[X<x]=\Phi(z)$ where $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $\Phi$ is the CDF of the normal distribution. We will show that for $x=\frac{p}{4}$, the resulting value is $1-\delta(n)$ for a negligible function $\delta(n)$. We first prove that the standard deviation is less than $\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ and then we show that the function $1-\Phi(z)$ with the aforementioned $z$ is negligible, and as a result we will see that the above probability is $1-\delta(n)$ for some negligible function $\delta(n)$.
Standard Deviation Upper Bound - we first want to prove that the standard deviation of $\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_\alpha$ is less than $\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log n}}$. First, due to the properties of standard deviation, and the discretization of $\Psi_{\alpha}$ the standard deviation of $\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha}$ is $\alpha\cdot p$, thus $\text{Var}(\overline{\Psi}_{\alpha})=\alpha^2\cdot p^2$. Due to probability rules and the explanation provided when discussing additive sum distribution, the variance of the additive sum distribution $\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_\alpha$ is $\text{Var}(\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_\alpha)=k\cdot\alpha^2\cdot p^2$, which means that the standard deviation of it is $\sqrt{k}\cdot p\cdot\alpha$. The following holds:$$\begin{array}{c}m=1.1\cdot n\log p<1.1\cdot n\log (2n^2)=\\=2.2\cdot n\cdot(\log 2 + \log n)\underset{n>2}{<}4.4n\cdot\log n\end{array}$$
We can therefore say that $m=o(n\log(n))$, therefore we get:$$\sqrt{k}\cdot\alpha\cdot p<\sqrt{m}\cdot\alpha\cdot p=o(\sqrt{n\log n})\cdot o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(n)}\right)\cdot p =o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right)\cdot p$$
For simplicity we will assume: $\sqrt{k}\cdot\alpha\cdot p = \frac{p}{\sqrt{\log n}}$
Therefore we can say that the standard deviation of $e\sim\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_{\alpha}$ is less than $\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log n}}$
Negligibility - We know that $\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}<\frac{p}{4}$ and specifically the difference is less than 1 at most. We also know that - in normal distributions. $$\Pr\left[X<x\right] =\Phi(z), z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$ Where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. For our distribution we know that $\mu=0$ and that $\sigma<\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log{n}}}$ which means that $z=\frac{x}{\sigma}>\frac{x}{\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log{n}}}}$. We define $x=\frac{p}{4}$ which is sufficient in our purposes (as $e$ is taken from $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ which will only hold whole values, therefore taking $\frac{p}{4}$ gives us a slightly better assurance). We therefore get:$$\Pr_{e\sim\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_\alpha}\left[|e|<\frac{p}{4}\right]=\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{p}{4}}{\sigma}\right)>\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{p}{4}}{\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log{n}}}}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)$$
We also know that $\Phi(z)=1-(1-\Phi(z))$, we will now prove that when $z=\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}$, the function $1-\Phi(z)$ is negligible in $n$.
We know from probability theory that $$\begin{array}{c}1-\Phi(z)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}}e^{-t^2/2}\text{dt}\approx\\\\\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)^2}{2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi\log{n}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{\log{n}}{32}}\end{array}$$
We used the approximation that $1-\Phi(z)\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot z}e^{-z^2/2}$.
To prove that this is negligilble with regards to $n$, we will show that the following holds $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(1-\Phi(z))\cdot n^c}=0,\ \ \forall c>0$, as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(1-\Phi(z))\cdot n^c}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi\log{n}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{\log{n}}{32}}\cdot n^c}\underset{n^c=e^{c\log n}}{=}\\
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi\log{n}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{\log{n}}{32}+c\log{n}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi\log{n}}\cdot{e^{\frac{\log{n}}{32}-c\log{n}}}}}=0
\end{array}$$
As a result, we found that $1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)$ is a negligible function.
Therefore we have shown that - given our selection of parameters:
$$\Pr_{e\sim\overline{\Psi}^{\star k}_\alpha}\left[|e|<\frac{p}{4}\right]>\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)=1-\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)\right)=1-\delta(n)$$
Where $\delta(n)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log{n}}}{4}\right)$ is a negligible function.

While I didn't check each exact implication in your answer, the overall argument is one that works, though explicitly fiddling around with $\Phi$ is typically not useful in lattice-based cryptography. I'll post an answer that is more typical.

I'll assume that we have a sample
$$e = \sum_{i = 1}^k\lfloor px_i\rceil\bmod p,$$
where $x_i\sim \mathcal{D}$ are i.i.d. from some distribution $\mathcal{D}$.
There are several parts of this that are atypically presented compared to "modern" lattice cryptography.
I'll mention them quickly.

$\mathcal{D}$ is distributed on $\mathbb{T} := \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, e.g. on the interval $[-1/2,1/2)$ equipped with $\bmod 1$ addition and multiplication. Note that for such $x_i$, $px_i$ is distributed on $[-p/2, p/2)\cong \mathbb{R}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and then $\lfloor px_i\rceil$ is distributed on $[-p/2, p/2)\cap \mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Modern authors generally ignore these several translation steps, and instead define some distribution $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ directly on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

It is not clearly useful to analyze $|e\bmod p|$. Implicitly, the main thing one hopes to do is to write $|e\bmod p| \stackrel{\ast}{\leq} |e|$, and then analyze $\Pr[|e| \leq p/4]$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. It is not really clear how one could get tighter bounds without applying inequality $\ast$. As a basic example of this, $|e\bmod p|$ doesn't even formally mean anything until you fix an embedding $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\mapsto \mathbb{Z}$.
So, it can help clean things up to instead define $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ directly over $\mathbb{Z}$. I'll note that in principle one could still get tighter bounds by analyzing $|\phi(e\bmod p)|$ rather than $|e|$ (which is implicity $\sum_{i = 1}^k \phi(x_i)$ --- this can be larger than $p/2$, while $|e\bmod p| \leq p/2$). I just don't think anyone has a reasonable argument why such bounds should be tighter (it would only "really matter" in situations the noise is so high where you would decrypt incorrectly a non-negligible amount of time), or how to compute them.


So, the modern argument would instead let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$, and then ask one to analyze
$$
e = \sum_{i= 1}^kx_i,
$$
and perhaps show that
$$
\Pr[|e| \leq p/4] \geq 1-\mathsf{negl}(n). 
$$
This is simple to do using the Chernoff-Cramer argument for a general class of $\mathcal{D}$.
The high level idea is to note that, for any increasing function $f(x)$, Markov's inequality implies that
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr[e > p/4] &= \inf_{\lambda>0}\Pr[\lambda e > \lambda p/4]\
&= \inf_{\lambda>0} \Pr[f(\lambda e) > f(\lambda p/4)]\
&\inf_{\lambda>0}\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(\lambda e)]}{f(\lambda p/4)}.
\end{align*}
So far, it is not clear that we gained anything.
Choosing $f(x) := \exp(x)$, we can simplify the expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(\lambda e)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda\sum_{i=1}^k x_i)] \stackrel{1}{=} \prod_{i = 1}^k\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda x_i)] \stackrel{2}{=}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda x_1)]^n,
$$
where (1) uses independence of the $x_i$'s, and (2) uses that they are identically distributed.
Then, provided $\mathcal{D}$ is such that one can get nice bounds on $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda x_i)] \leq \exp(\sigma^2\lambda^2/2)$ (the typical term is "sub-Gaussian", and a typical reference is Section 2 of Vershynin), one gets that
$$
\Pr[|e| > p/4] \leq \inf_{\lambda>0} \exp(-\lambda p/4)\exp(n\lambda^2\sigma^2/2) = \exp(-\frac{\lambda p}{2} + n\lambda^2\sigma^2/2).
$$
Minimizing the numerator $g(\lambda)$ of $\exp(g(\lambda))$ (set $\lambda$ to be such that $g'(\lambda) = 0$, or $\lambda = \frac{p}{4n\sigma^2}$) then yields that
$$
\Pr[e>p/4] \leq \exp(-\frac{p^2}{8\sigma^2n} +\frac{p^2}{32n\sigma^2}) = \exp(-\frac{3p^2}{32n\sigma^2}).
$$
This has the benefit that it works for a wide variety of distributions $\mathcal{D}$, for example

continuous Gaussians,
discrete Gaussians,
binomial random variables,
bounded random variables.

All are sometimes used in lattice-based cryptography, generally because it is surprisingly difficult to accurately sample from discrete Gaussians in constant time.
